# PHP create .less file referenceable by Drupal

Tags: php, css, http, drupal, less

I am trying to create a custom module that programmatically creates a LESS file.

I created a menu callback that is a file. Here is hook_menu()...

```
$items['sites/all/themes/universal/less/dynamic.css.less'] = array(
  'page callback' => 'jobs_universal_lessvars',
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
);
```

Here is the callback.

```
function jobs_universal_lessvars(){ 
  header('Content-type: text/css');
  $output = '
    @color: #4D926F;
    body.notaclass {
      color:@color;
    }
  ';
  print $output;
}
```

And I call this to add it.

```
function universal_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme','universal').'/less/dynamic.css.less');
}
```

I uploaded a static file with the exact same content to the above ^^ path, disabled the menu callback, and it processed/applied correctly. When I try to run this module, the processed "CSS" file is not included in the HTML and I get an error saying

> LESS error: load error: failed to find
>   sites/all/themes/universal/less/dynamic.css.less

Before you answer...

1. I have the LESS module installed
2. I have the LESS library uploaded correctly
3. I have tested that I can include a static .less file and have it process
4. I have tested the menu callback by manually going to the URL
5. I have tried it with and without calling header('Content-type: text/css');

I get it... it's not a file. But it "is", right? I could just call this function and have it create a new CSS file that's added, but it doesn't fulfil the requirements of the module. Help me? :) Programmatically creating files is very new to me!

Comment: Try actually creating the file every time if your web directory is writable by your webserver user. You may be right, it's not technically a file and thus maybe that's why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Case closed, I found this; https://drupal.org/node/2139603
-- It's a Drupal "hook" that makes LESS variables available to .less files that are included.

Files on the server are interacting with each other through the file system, it's only interpreted as a file if it's requested by a browser.

I'll set the variables programatically through that Drupal hook instead of creating a .less file that has those variables. Thank you for your patience everyone, my dev knowledge is narrow!!